# How to add another layer to GeoPackage in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

QGIS 2.12 has support for saving a layer on the map in the GeoPackage format and that is great. However, I don't see a way to add another layer to the GPKG file, even though GeoPackage supports multiple layers. Is this functionality that is yet to come in QGIS or is there a way to do  it with QGIS 2.12?

Comment: At least you do it from command line with ogr2ogr tool.

Comment: `ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" out.gpkg in.[shp|gpkg] -append -update`

Answer (score 30):

I'm seeing this years later, but if someone still wonders...

In addition to the "save as" method, with QGIS 3.0, you can click and drag layers inside a GeoPackage within the Browser panel.

Comment: This worked great for me.   I had to create several different layers with the same basic Attributes(fields) .   I just kept dragging them in from a file and re-naming them.    Thanks!

Comment: thank you, this saved so much time!

Comment: I discovered that (QGIS 3.10) you can create a new GeoPackage layer and specify the GeoPackage file you aleady have, and QGIS will warn you whether you want to "Overwrite" or "Add Layer" to existing file.

Answer (score 8):

You could use DB Manager in Menu >> Databases.

1. Select the Database (Spatialite/Geopackage)
2. Import layer

Comment: This method works for me using spatialite but not for geopackage. I get "error 11 connetion to database failed".

Comment: BTW I forgot to mention that I'm using QGIS 2.14.9

Answer (score 7):

Right Click on the layer --> Export --> Save features as, change format to GeoPackage and choose the existing geopackage, change the layer name to what you wish and save.

Comment: This approach works for me.

Answer (score 1):

DB Manager seems to have a bug working with geopackage data and can't be used to add another layer to a geopackage. You can use the 'save as' functionality in versions 2.18.1 and above. See: [Add layer to existing geopackage not working in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224008/add-layer-to-existing-geopackage-not-working-in-qgis?noredirect=1#comment345720_224008).