# Geopackage - select on geometry column returns null

Tags: sql, qgis-2, geopackage

In DB Manager in QGIS 2.18.26

I want to select geometries in geopackage table.
The returned geometry column is null but the source layer can be loaded as a geometry table in Qgis and i can read the geometry text.

Source Layer:
[image: Source layer with text geometry]

Select on geometry column
[image: Select on geometry columns return NULL values]
[image]

How can i get the geometries?

EDIT: Here is the [file](https://gate16sprl-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jean-louis_stanus_gate-16_com/ERVnXrSag01MtfQZjXeM4YUBSCrVKutXgGbs7VSNCIpm1w?e=4Ua029)

Comment: Use just `select geom from deljin*_lines`. Or `select ST_AsText(geom)…`if you want to see the WKT presentation of geometries.

Comment: nothing returned with the simple select  or with `select ST_AsText(geom)`

Comment: I added the gpkg file

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/224020/120129

Comment: you have different names for the fields "id" and "fid", as well as "geom" and "geometry" ...select  * from delijn_lines_za;
select * from delijn_stops;
select * from delijn_lines;

Answer (score 4):

I also get empty values when I query the geopackage. (I tried both, QGIS 2.18.26 and 3.6)  Perhaps it is a bug...

But, when you query the qgis-layers on the other hand, the query returns results.

- In DB-manager go to virtual layers > QGIS layers
- add following query:

  `select AsText(geometry)  as geom, * from "transports_en_commun delijn_lines"`

You get a result.

[image]

Comment: Exactly the same behavior here with QGIS 3.8.3-Zanzibar

Comment: @PauloCardoso more info on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27914