# DB Manager returns NULL for GeoPackage layers

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer, qgsexpression

When I try to do some spatial query in the DB Manager (as Virtual Layer Provider) or in the Virtual Layer Window (Layer > Add new Layer > Create Virtual Layer...) it returns a NULL array, as it doesn't understand the GEOM field.

This happens with GPKG and KML. Although it doesn't happen with SHP. I tried with a KML layer (original), then I converted to GPKG and SHP. When queried in the BD Manager in GeoPackage Provider, it worked.

Is this an issue or exists an explanation?

I searched about it, but I didn't understand the conclusion.

*DISCUSSION:*
[Geopackage - select on geometry column returns null](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313769/geopackage-select-on-geometry-column-returns-null) ;
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27914

Comment: I tried the same query for all them.
`SELECT * FROM layer`
`SELECT st_buffer(geom, 1) FROM layer`

Comment: The first one is a control query: worked well with all formats. The second the test. Others `ST_` have the same result.