# Append (only) new features to a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, append

I've got a vector layer `Target`. I want to periodically add features that arrive (with the same attributes) in `new.csv`, which was created in the field.

I'd like to append them to `Target` if and only if they're not already there. I don't want to duplicate existing features, and I want to keep any tweaks done in `Target`, i.e. I don't want to replace existing features from `new.csv` either. (The features have a unique and consistent ID in a `Name` field.)

What's the simplest way to do this, in a way that can easily be (semi)automated to run weekly? I can think of the following, but seeking advice before I reinvent the wheel:

1. Use the `merge` processing algorithm and then postprocess to delete duplicates, making `new.csv` have a flag in a each feature's comment field to know which duplicate to nuke.
2. Dust off my rusty SQL and run some sort of `APPEND` query in DB Manager, with an `EXCEPT` clause to skip what's already in `Target`?
3. Write a PyQGIS script to traverse the features in `new.csv`, throw out those where `Name` is already in `Target`, and then use `layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(featureList)` to add what's left to `Target`.

Suggestions? I don't think it matters, but the feature geometry are points in EPSG:4326. `Target` is one of several layers in a gpkg, and `new.csv` is of course a separate comma separated file, which can be imported as a layer with point geometry.

Comment: right click 'save as' target? QGIS 2.81+ will append/update existing gpkg https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224008/add-layer-to-existing-geopackage-not-working-in-qgis

Comment: @Mapperz, thanks, but I'm looking to add the (missing) features to the existing layer, which happens to be in a gpkg, not to append a new layer to the gpkg database. Will edit for extra clarity.

Comment: Another method would be to add an action to the layer (layer properties > actions), so you can just click a button in the attribute table and the layer updates. You would have to figure out how to code that though, probably in python. https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#add-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method. I think this is one of the easiest methods to set up, because you don't have to brush off / re-learn any coding skills. But it's not the most efficient to use, because you do have to do select the inputs every time.

You can set up a simple graphical processing model to do this.

- Model inputs: 2 vector layers: `original layer` and `layer with new features`
- Algorithm: `Extract by attribute`

  - input: `layer with new features`
  - parameters: field `new` (type the field name *without* quotation marks) equals 1
  - output: leave blank
- Algorithm: `Merge vector layers`

  - inputs: `original layer` and `'Extracted (attribute)' from algorithm 'Extract by attributes'`
  - output: `updated layer`

[image]

[image]

*Downsides of this method:*

- You do have to select the two layers when you run the model.
- You may have to import the CSV into the project before you can run this model. When running the  model, if you click the `...` button next to the dropdown to select the layer, you do have the option to select a layer that isn't loaded into the project, but that doesn't seem to work with CSV files.

*Notes*:

I assumed your CSV layer has a field called "new" and new features have "new" = 1. You can use a different operator and a calculated expression in the `merge vector layer` algorithm. For example, assume you have a "date created" field. Using the operator "greater than" and an expression like `now() - to_interval( '1 week')` will append all the features that were created in the past week.

You could even make one of the inputs for the model a text string where you enter a length of time (eg '1 week', '5 days', '3 months and 2 days') and use that in the `to_interval()` function in that example.

Comment: Thanks @csk. I'll investigate processing models, an area of QGIS I haven't yet explored. I will need to go further on the selection of which features are "new" - basically my current kluge is something like your interval < 1 week suggestion but my reason for revisiting is that I collect data points some of which are actually older than one week. So "new" needs to be defined as "not in `Target`". But this is a useful other framework for me to explore!

Comment: This sent me down the right path. To get the new features dynamically, I used the algorithm `Execute SQL` with the query `SELECT * FROM input2 WHERE Photo NOT IN (SELECT input1.Photo FROM input1 INNER JOIN input2 WHERE input1.Photo=input2.Photo)` (Master is 1st input, the raw .csv layer including new 2nd)  instead of `Extract by attribute`. And instead of merging (which generates a new layer) I do a copy-paste of the output back into Master, which I'll automate as a Python layer action later.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. Please post your method as another answer. That will be helpful to others with the same question.

Answer (score 3):

Circling back with what I've done, a pastiche of the other answers/comments here plus some of my own playing around.

I have a `Master` layer (in a gpkg) and a `Raw.csv` that is updated on return from fieldwork. (The shell command to update the .csv file is a layer action.)

I then use the processing algorithm `Execute SQL` with the query `SELECT * FROM input2 WHERE Photo NOT IN (SELECT input1.Photo FROM input1 INNER JOIN input2 WHERE input1.Photo=input2.Photo)` (Master is 1st input, Raw 2nd; note `Photo` is what I called `Name` in the question).

This is the first step in a graphical model that does some other corrections (e.g. a camera with a date function that is off) and finally outputs a temporary memory layer of the cleaned-up new features and attributes.

I then manually select-all, copy, paste to `Master`.

I've discovered the [AppendFeaturesToLayer](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer) plug-in, which would let me bypass the manual copy-paste, but for the moment I appreciate the forced safety check of looking at the new feature attributes before they get committed to the master.

Comment: I just have to chime in that the Append plugin should be added as a native processing tool. As long as we can create an empty layer with the correct table schema, writing iterative process results from the graphical modeler to a single layer with that plugin is a huge time-saver.